# Jest unexpected token error with React-Native tsx

Tags: typescript, react-native, testing, jestjs

I attempted to run Jest tests for TypeScript code in a React Native project. I expected the tests to run without errors. However, I encountered the

> Jest encountered an unexpected token error

when using the statement `import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';`. The error occurred during the test execution, and I'm seeking a solution to resolve it and make the tests run as expected.
How can I resolve this issue and run Jest tests successfully?